# Lines with popup values and route sums

Tags: mapbox

I'm newer to Mapbox and have struggled to find this answer in the documention; there's so much, it's a bit overwhelming at first. I'm doing some calculations locally and uploading the results as a geojson which includes segments of many roads and a number to go with each segment. E.g. road segment A has a numeric value of 1, and road segment B has a numeric value of 3. I'd like to do two things:

1. Set it so that these road segments have popup boxes displaying the value. I'm currently loading them and displaying their color based on this value, but I can't seem to find a way to add a popup to those segments which would display that value; all the popup documentation I find is focused on points.
2. Create an option which would evaluate navigation routes by summing all the numeric values of the segments encountered along the route. So if a route went through the above two segments (A and B) it would show a value of 4 at the end.

I'm doing all this in browser so none of the SDKs are needed as far as I can tell, though I think mapbox-GL might be needed. I'm at a loss as to where to start; any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can also replace the onClick event listener with an event listener that listens onHover or else. To make it work, just replace `<Your_Access_Token>` with Your Access Token.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a GeoJSON line</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<Your_Access_Token>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  "name": "Hello, world!"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
  
  map.on('click', 'route', function (e) {
  new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.name)
    .addTo(map);
  });
 
  // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the states layer.
  map.on('mouseenter', 'route', function () {
     map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });
 
  // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
  map.on('mouseleave', 'route', function () {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! To make sure I'm understanding though, I've already loaded my geojson in a Mapbox Studio instance and created a layer from it. The above would seem to load that geojson again; is this a separate usage? Or would I just strip the geojson piece and put the rest of the above in as extra code for that map layer?

Comment: Also, I'm not immediately seeing the summation of that extra value in the route instance; is that in this or were you just addressing the first point?

Comment: This is an example of displaying a customizable popUp onClick of a lineString based layer.  You do not need to reload the geojson if you already have a layer based on a lineString. I was not addressing the second point with this answer.